# $t\to||f-f_t||_p$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

$f\in L^p(R)$. For $t\in R$,define$f_t:R\to R$ by $f_t(x)=f(x-t)$ then the function $t \to||f-f_t||_p$ is  uniformly continuous.
I have proved it for simple functions.But then using that to prove for f seems quite difficult to me.
Am I doing something wrong? Any other way to solve this?

Comment: Approximate $f$ in $L^{p}$ norm by a continuous function with compact support.

Comment: If I take continuous function with compact support, say g.\ Suppose I prove it for g. 
I want to show now for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that  | $||f-f_t||_p - ||f-f_{t'}||_p $| $< \epsilon$ when $|t-t'|< \delta$. How to bring g here. This is the same problem I was facing while doing with simple functions.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon >0$ we can find a continuous function with compact support such that $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$. Now $$|\|f-f_t\|-\|f-f_s\||$$ $$\leq \|f_t-f_s\|$$ $$\leq \|f_t-g_t\|+\|g_t-g_s\|+\|f_s-g_s\|$$ $$=\|f-g\|+\|g_t-g_s\|+\|f-g\|$$.  Finish the proof by showing that the result holds when $f$ is replaced by $g$.